# request response issue using python3

Tags: python-3.x

I check my domains with request (rest) in the for loop. But if 200 not return, i m getting `connection refused, connection timeout etc` errors. How can I list 200 returning domains and not returning ?

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host=
```

```
response = requests.get("http://" + domains + URL, headers=headers).status_code
if response == 200:
   print("working")
else:
   print("not working")
```

How can I handle if the url not connected or connection refused ?

Answer (score 2):

To gather a list of all the domains that did not throw a connection exception and returned a 200 response, you could store them in a list. Here's an example that also stores all the bad domains:

```
good_domains = []
bad_domains = []

for domain in domains:
    try:
        response = requests.get(f"http://{domain}{URL}", headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            good_domains.append(domain)
        else:
            bad_domains.append(domain)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        bad_domains.append(domain)

print(f"The domains that successfully connected with a 200 response code are {good_domains}")
print(f"The domains that failed to connect or had a status code != 200 are {bad_domains}")
```

Comment: It will face the error if the url not response as follows.

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='responsemetadata', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb50f097fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
`

Comment: In that case you could add a try/except block to account for the error. I updated my answer with the proper exception handling